# ASP.NET Dropdownlist Issue duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a drop down list that pulls a list of last names.  The problem is some people have the same last name and for some reason it always shows one name.  The drop down list is connected to a sql server and here is the code for the drop down list:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="lName" DataValueField="lName" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and here is the SqlDataSource:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [lName] FROM [CoaTest]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to show Smith three times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `SELECT DISTINCT` in your sql. When using `DISTINCT`, it will load all of the results from your query, and then select the distinct values. So in your case, if you have these last names returned as your result set

```
Smith
Markson
Smith
Henson
Smith
Henson
```

It will select the distinct values from that, and ultimately return

```
Smith
Markson
Henson
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb lol! Thank you for catching that!!! And thank you for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is selecting `DISTINCT` values.

`SELECT DISTINCT [lName] FROM [CoaTest]`

If you want all values returned then remove the DISTINCT keyword.